# Jquery script source in file won't load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making validator of textboxes in asp.net Web Forms. For example show error if value of textbox 5 is bigger than value of textbox 6. I tried to use validator engine from here:

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

The thing is, when I try to reference to the engine in file Scripts, it doesn't load.

Here is script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-cz.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#ctl01").validationEngine();
    });
    /**
    *
    * @param {jqObject} the field where the validation applies
    * @param {Array[String]} validation rules for this field
    * @param {int} rule index
    * @param {Map} form options
    * @return an error string if validation failed
    */
</script>
```

and error here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndVrO.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace `~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js` with `Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js`

Comment: @AlexSlipknot this will make it search in the current folder use `/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js` instead for the root folder.

Comment: @Tarek.Eladly indeed. I thought he needs relative path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-cz.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#ctl01").validationEngine();
    });
    /**
    *
    * @param {jqObject} the field where the validation applies
    * @param {Array[String]} validation rules for this field
    * @param {int} rule index
    * @param {Map} form options
    * @return an error string if validation failed
    */
</script>
```

`~` is used for relevant path so it is looking for the script in the wrong location.